# What is sendmail referring to here?

Tags: linux, sendmail, hostname

When I install sendmail from the debian repos, I get the following output:

```
Disabling HOST statistics file(/var/lib/sendmail/host_status).
Creating /etc/mail/sendmail.cf...
Creating /etc/mail/submit.cf...
Informational: confCR_FILE file empty: /etc/mail/relay-domains
Informational: confCT_FILE file empty: /etc/mail/trusted-users
Updating /etc/mail/access...
Updating /etc/mail/aliases...
WARNING: local host name (ixtmixilix) is not qualified; see cf/README: WHO AM I?
```

Can someone please tell me what this means, what I need to do to qualify my hostname?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's referring to [this page](https://www.sendmail.org/%7Eca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/whoami.html) from the readme, which tells you how to specify your hostname. It's warning you that your hostname won't work outside your local network; sendmail attaches your hostname as the sender of the message, but it's going to be useless on the other end because people outside your local network can't find the machine `ixtmixilix`. You should specify a hostname that can be resolved from anywhere, like `ixtmixilix.example.com`

Comment: Where should I put the line suggested in the docs? (`Dmbar.com
define(`confDOMAIN_NAME', `$w.$m')dnl`) Is it in `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`?

Comment: in `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf` , then `.mc` will be updated automatically after running : `sendmailconfig` cmd

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI You sure that’s not the other way around? Edit `sendmail.mc`, and `.cf` will be updated?

Comment: @JezenThomas It does seem like it's the other way. It only fixed it for me when I edited `sendmail.mc`.

Answer (score 11):

For me on Ubuntu 14.04 that solved the problem:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/hostname
```

Change your host name to something like my-domain.XXX

Where XXX = .com OR .net OR .some

Then `sudo sendmailconfig` updated all the rest
You can test your configuration so:

```
$ sendmail -v username@privateDomain.ext < test.mail
```

I used my private domain email box as services such as gmail block these kind of email:

`050 550-5.7.1 [87.68.229.9      12] Our system has detected that this message is
050 550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail,
050 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit
050 550 5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/188131 for more information. u3si25544809wje.160 - gsmtp`

Where `test.mail` is a file containing whatever message you wish to send

Comment: didn't worked for me

Comment: @PJunior, thank you for the remark, fixed! it was test.mail - file name

Comment: I was talking about the edition on /etc/hostname/

Comment: @PJunior, its a file, not a folder, hence /etc/hostname - usually holds your machine name. Try this command: cat /etc/hostname, if you get your machine name as: XXX, just edit this file and rename your machine to XXX.com or XXX.some or any other FQDN

Comment: Yes, i'v edit it. Didn't worked :/ but emails are being sent

Comment: strange, did you logout/in? restart/reboot? what do you get on cat /etc/hostname?

Comment: Oh :) I might need to reboot then...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26049/discussion-between-jadeye-and-pjunior).

Comment: In my setup, after the `nano /etc/hostname` step before the `sendmailconfig` step, I had to do `hostname -b -F /etc/hostname` otherwise sendmail didn't register that I had changed the hostname

Answer (score 7):

On Debian 8 (Jessie) works:

`$ sudo hostnamectl set-hostname yourdomain.com`

Then test it this way:

`$ hostname
yourdomain.com`

Comment: This also worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Also Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

This output refers to a [Fully-qualified domain name (FQDN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). Which is either an IP address or a domain name (something with a dot in it).

Answer (score -1):

Just edit your hostname by editinig:

`sudo vim /etc/hostname`

And also update your env:

`export HOSTNAME=yourhostname.com`